# Sandbox Paypal webhook integration

Tags: java, spring-boot, paypal

I am trying to integrate paypal webhook with my application. I have created an app in which I have configured webhook (entered the url and selected events) after that I am using webhook simulator to raise an event. I am using spring boot rest api in backend to receive webhook call. The API is of POST method type and just logging that i have received a call.

But api call is not triggrered.

Also I have checked for Webhook Events, No events has been generated till now.

For reference,
[image: The Webhook Events]

Please help !!

P.S I am using sandbox for testing

Answer (score 0):

If anyone facing same problem, please do check your listener server is having sha-2 compatible certs.

This is due to sha-2 compatible certs.
Paypal requires the listener to be sha-2 compatible.